# Git Merge Request Filter by folder

Tags: git, gitlab, git-log

I have a GIT repo with different branches. Branch has 5 folders as source code. Different developers generate merge request for different folders. Is there any way that i can generate a report which shows me merge request according to folder. I am specific about folders so other GIT log might not help.

Ashish

Comment: Try `git log <branch> -- <path>`.

Comment: You have a command to list all the pull requests ?